# Finding the minimum distance in a table

Tags: algorithm, minimum

I have a table of dimension m * n as given below

```
2    6    9    13
1    4    12   21
10   14   16   -1
```

Few constraints about this table:

1. Elements in each row is sorted in increasing order (natural
   ordering).
2. A -1 means the cell is of no significance for the purpose of
   calculatio, i.e. no element exists there.
3. No element can appear in a row after a -1.
4. All the cells can have either a positive number  between 0 and N or
   a -1.
5. No two cells have the same positive numbe, i.e. a -1 can appear
   multiple times but no other number can.

Question: I would like to find a set S of n numbers from the table where the set must contain only one number from each row and **the max(S) - min(S) is as small as possible.**

For e.g. the above table gives me S = 12,13,14.

I would really appreciate if this can be solved. My solution is complicated and it takes    `O(m^n)` and this is too much. I want an optimal solution.

Comment: An optimal solution in terms of space, time, or exactness? Or all of these.

Comment: An optimal solution in terms of time. Exactness is must(i.e. I want the highlighted thing and there is no compromise on that)

Comment: @dharam: This is an interesting problem. Why did you want to solve it? How did it arise?

Comment: @Tom: I was a part of a bigger problem... The problem was to find the minimum window in a string in which a sequence of characters occur... Example: Consider a string "abzyxcdcbgahjkcbabghjcbja" and i want to find the sequence "abc" in any order. The only criteria is that the window should have minimum length. And for this example the window length is 3 and the sequence occurs in the order cba

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Put positions of all first elements of each row into priority queue (min-heap).
2. Remove smallest element from the queue and replace it with the next element from the same row.
3. Repeat step 2 until no more elements different from "-1" are left in some row. Calculate max(S) - min(S) for each iteration and if it is smaller than any previous value, update the best-so-far set S.

Time complexity is O(m*n*log(m)).

Comment: Thanks.. this solution works perfectly fine for few of the test cases I have worked upon. Thanks for this. It's really easy to code.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a brute force `O((m*n)^2 * nlog(m))` algorithm that I can prove works:

```
min <- INFINITY
For each 2 numbers in different rows, let them be a,b
   for each other row: 
        check if there is a number between a and b
    if there is a matching number in every other row:
        min <- min{min,|a-b|}
```

**Explanation:**

Checking if there is a number between a and b can be done using binary search, and is `O(logm)`

There are `O((n*m)^2)` different possibilities for a,b.

The idea is to exhaustively check the pair which creates the maximal difference, and check if it gives a "feasible" solution(all other elements in this solution are in range [a,b]), and get the pair that minimizes the difference between all "feasible" solutions .

---

**EDIT**: removed the 2nd solution I proposed, which was greedy and wrong.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Please see my approach:
For element e1 in first row I find the element e2 in row 2 such that |e1-e2| is minimum. Then for e2 find an element e3 in row 3 such that |e2-e3| is minimum. Repeat this for aall the elements in row 1 and you will get various sets of n numbers each. 

In every set check the value max(s) - min(s). The minimum of all these values is your answer. But how to convert this in a program is my actual problem.

Comment: @dharam: This solution is definetly wrong: line1=5,-1,... ; line2 = 3,6,-1,...; line3= 2,8,-1,...; line4=1,10,-1,...; the suggested solution will return {5,6,8,10}, while the optimal is {5,3,2,1}. The second solution I suggeted also fails for this case (I will delete the second solution).

Comment: We do not take into account the -1.

Comment: @dharam: I know, look at the example - it doesn't take it into account and it is a counter example for the proposed algorithms.

Comment: got you. You are absolutely right. My solution won't work in this case. I am trying to code your solution but I am having hard time. :(